# Convert a compressed string to lower case

Tags: sas

After comprising 4 variable names into a new variable that is written out of their names separated with `"/"`, I need to make the string in small letters as well. Currently after compressing it looks like this:

```
ArizonaDiamondbacks/Aquino,Greg/325000/Pitcher
```

Where do I apply the `lowcase` function?

```
data MON2; set MON;
COMBO=COMPRESS(Team||"/"||Name||"/"||Salary||"/"||Position);
run;
proc print data=MON2; run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround `compress()` with `lowcase()`. This will convert the whole string to lower case at once. Alternatively you could surround each of `team`, `name`, etc. with `lowcase()`, but it's more efficient to just call it once on the concatenated string.

```lua
data mon2;
    set mon;
    combo = lowcase(compress(catx("/", team, name, salary, position)))
run;

proc print data = mon2;
run;
```

As a matter of personal preference I used `catx()`. This concatenates strings and separates the pieces with a slash in this case.